# Using GNUwin patch

Tags: command-prompt, gnu, patch

In the bin folder I have the file I want to change, *AppFilters.groovy*
and the patch produced by WinMerge- *app.patch*
When I run...

```
 patch.exe AppFilters.groovy < app.patch
```

...a command console opens, but is blank and doesn't do anything.

The patch file looks like

```
58c58
<       search(controller:'*', action:'search'){
```

This is a very small patch because I want to get the workflow working before I do it across a whole directory. However, I can't get even this simple patch to work.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer buried in the Internet. Windows doesn't like files named "patch". Could be scary, right Windows? So I renamed patch.exe to pch.exe and it ran fine. Depending on the folder you are modifying you may also have to Run As Adminstrator command prompt.